# How to colorize last window in status line?

Tags: tmux

I'd like to make the last selected window (the one to which `:last-window` takes you) to stand out visually. By default it's just marked with an inconspicuous `-` after the name.

Is there a way to set the attributes for last window name in the status line, like `set-option window-status-current` does for the current window name?

Update: Both Debian Wheezy (stable) and Ubuntu 12.04 have tmux 1.6 that lacks the necessary option. But there's a backport which is 1.9.

The solution was to upgrade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there might be a version mis-match or something, but jasonwryan was on the right track for my purposes. I'm using tmux v1.8, and I see the following options in the man page that work:

```
         window-status-last-attr attributes
                 Set status line attributes for the last active window.

         window-status-last-bg colour
                 Set status line background colour for the last active window.

         window-status-last-fg colour
                 Set status line foreground colour for the last active window.
```

An example for your `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g window-status-last-attr bold
set -g window-status-last-fg blue
```

---

**EDIT**: Sure enough, these options were added for tmux v1.8. Thus, this answer is applicable for tmux versions >=1.8 only.

**EDIT**: Per jasonwryan, his solution is for v1.9+. After reviewing the changelog, the foo-{bg,fg,attr} commands are deprecated as of v1.9 and will be slowly phased out. Best to use jasonwryans solution if on v1.9+.

**EDIT**: Implemented this in the form of a pull request for the popular status line utility `powerline`. https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline/pull/864. This pull request has since been merged.

Comment: I'm actually running 1.9_a...

Comment: Both answers were equally worthy; I'm accepting the answer of the user with less rep.

Comment: is there any updates on this as the bg / background does not seem to be working anymore...trying `set-option -g window-status-last-style bg=dd6600,italics,curly-underscore
set-option -g window-status-last-bg #dd6600` (either of these lines before) and I am just getting the italic and underscore and no other changes

Answer (score 4):

In tmux 1.9, you want the `window-status-last-style` option. From the manual:

> window-status-last-style style
>                      Set status line style for the last active window.  For how to specify style, see the message-command-style option.

An example would be:

```
set -g window-status-last-style fg=yellow,bold
```